# How to plot a dashed line on seaborn lineplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm simply trying to plot a dashed line using seaborn. This is the code I'm using and the output I'm getting

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 11
x = np.linspace(0,2,n)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

sns.lineplot(x,y, linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just do `plt.plot(x,y, '--')` since you are anyway import `matplotlib.pyplot`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It seems that `linestyle=` argument doesn't work with `lineplot()`, and the argument `dashes=` is a bit more complicated than it might seem.

A (relatively) simple way of doing it might be to get a list of the Line2D objects on the plot using `ax.lines` and then set the linestyle manually:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 11
x = np.linspace(0,2,n)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

ax = sns.lineplot(x,y)

# Might need to loop through the list if there are multiple lines on the plot
ax.lines[0].set_linestyle("--")

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Update:**

It appears the `dashes` argument applies only when plotting multiple lines (usually using a pandas dataframe). Dashes are specified the same as in matplotlib, a tuple of (segment, gap) lengths. Therefore, you need to pass a list of tuples.

```
n = 100
x = np.linspace(0,4,n)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = np.cos(2*np.pi*x)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[y1, y2]) # modified @Elliots dataframe production

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, dashes=[(2, 2), (2, 2)])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you also need to define the `style` parameter to let it work. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485426/markers-are-not-visible-in-seaborn-plot

Answer (score 23):

In the current version of seaborn 0.11.1, your code works perfectly fine.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 11
x = np.linspace(0,2,n)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

sns.lineplot(x=x,y=y, linestyle='--')
plt.show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

As has been mentioned before, seaborn's lineplot overrides the linestyle based on the `style` variable, which according to the docs can be a "name of variables in data *or vector data*".
Note the second option of directly passing a vector to the `style` argument.
This allows the following simple trick to draw dashed lines even when plotting only single lines, either when providing the data directly or as dataframe:

If we provide a constant style vector, say `style=True`, it will be broadcast to all data. Now we just need to set `dashes` to the desired *dash tuple* (sadly, 'simple' dash specifiers such as '--', ':', or 'dotted' are not supported), e.g. `dashes=[(2,2)]`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 111)
y = np.sin(x)
sns.lineplot(x, y, style=True, dashes=[(2,2)])
```

[image: simple lineplot with dashes]

Comment: How would you now remove "True" that shows up in legend?

Comment: According to the docs, you could just pass another option `legend=False` to sns.lineplot.

Comment: +1. Like Ravaging Care, I'm also looking for a way to remove 'True' from the legend, without removing the entire legend.

Answer (score 4):

You are in fact using `lineplot` the wrong way. Your simplified case is more appropriate for `matplotlib`'s `plot` function than anything from `seaborn`. `seaborn` is more for making the plots more readable with less direct intervention in the script, and generally gets the most mileage when dealing with `pandas` dataframes

For example

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100
x = np.linspace(0,2,n)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = np.sin(4*np.pi*x)
y3 = np.sin(6*np.pi*x)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[y1, y2, y3], index=x)

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

As to how to set the styles the way you want for the variables you're trying to show, that I'm not sure how to handle.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers work, they require a little bit more handiwork.

---

You can wrap your seaborn plot in an `rc_context`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 11
x = np.linspace(0,2,n)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

with plt.rc_context({'lines.linestyle': '--'}):
    sns.lineplot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

This results in the following plot.

[image: plot result]

If you would like to see other options regarding lines, have a look using the following line.

```
[k for k in plt.rcParams.keys() if k.startswith('lines')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sns.lineplot(df_input, x='value x', y='value y', linestyle='dashed')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! With 5 other answers here (all much better explained), what makes yours a "good answer" and worth upvoting (or even trying)? You can find more information in [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  It might be helpful to review some highly upvoted answers as examples to follow.  Thanks!