# Markers are not visible in seaborn plot

Tags: python, seaborn, markers

Here is an example:

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.lineplot(range(10), range(10), markers=True)
```

[image]

Why aren't there any markers although I set `markers=True`?

Answer (score 48):

Basically, because that's not what `markers=` is for. As [per the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html?highlight=lineplot#seaborn.lineplot):

> **markers** : boolean, list, or dictionary, optional
>
> Object determining
>   how to draw the markers for different levels of the style variable.
>   Setting to True will use default markers, or you can pass a list of
>   markers or a dictionary mapping levels of the style variable to
>   markers. Setting to False will draw marker-less lines. Markers are
>   specified as in matplotlib.

Therefore, `markers=` is only useful when you also specify a `style=` parameter. For example:

```
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", style="event", data=fmri, markers=True)
```

However, other kwargs are passed to `plt.plot()`, therefore, you can instruct `lineplot` to use markers by using the `marker=` kwarg (notice the lack of "s"):

```
ax = sns.lineplot(range(10), range(10), marker='o')
```

Comment: I do not want to use a dataframe to specify the data to visualize, though, I just want to pass lists as `x` and `y` values.. I think what is intuitive is that if there is no `data` passed, it should just use the default marker type when `markers=True`, given style is not a valid argument if there is no `data`.

Comment: Understood, but as ImportanceOfBeingErnest said in his other comment, seaborn is simply a helper designed to facilitate plotting dataframes. If you don't need those functionalities, then there is no reason to use it and you should instead plot directly using matplotlib

Answer (score 8):

A similar problem was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385428/plot-point-markers-and-lines-in-different-hues-but-the-same-style-with-seaborn). If you specify the matplotlib argument using `marker='*'` for example the markers will show up.

Comment: It's not a bug. It's just not meant to be used that way. (The comment below the linked answer is about the legend, which is buggy.)

Comment: I think the intended usage is not intuitive at all (see my comment in the other response).

Comment: That's why in the answer @BenT linked to, I collected the usual options you have. If you do not want to use the data structure seaborn assumes, there is little reason to use seaborn at all.