# Seaborne Linechart Style Causing Duplicate Legend Entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I'm using seaborn to plot the results of some work using Benford's Law. The plot has two axes: a barplot representing the relative frequency of the digits in the input data, and a linechart representing the expected frequencies from Benford's Law.

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963725/how-to-plot-a-dashed-line-on-seaborn-lineplot), I used the `style=True` option so that I could control the style of my line. Unfortunately, this causes a duplicate entry in my legend, which I can't seem to remove.  How can I correct the duplicate entry in my legend?

Current code:

```
def plot(inputdata, digits, y_col_actual, y_col_expected):

    plt.rcParams['patch.force_edgecolor']=True

    ax1 = sns.barplot(
        data=inputdata,
        x = digits,
        y = y_col_actual,
        color = '#B2E8C2',
        label='Actual Data'
        )
    ax1.set(ylabel='Relative Frequency')

    ax2 = sns.lineplot(
        data=inputdata,
        x = digits,
        y = y_col_expected,
        ax = ax1,
        zorder = 5,
        color = 'black',
        style=True,
        dashes=[(2,2)],
        markers=True,
        label='Benfords Law',
        )
    
    plt.show()
```

And the resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: What did you try to do with style? Style should be the name of a column in the DataFrame, is not a Boolean option. That's why it appears in the legend. Probably what you want to set is `dashes=True` or `linestyle='--'`

Comment: @jjsantoso style needs to be set in order to use dashes. There is only one line (no categories to distinguish), so I don't want to provide a column name - so True is a valid alternative. Setting dashes to True doesn't actually result in any dashed lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a very nice solution but this works for me when I append it to the end of your `plot` function:

```
handles, labels = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels[1] = "_True"
ax2.legend(handles, labels)
```

This works because `matplotlib` ignores any labels beginning with an underscore. Since in your case, `labels[1] = "True"` is the offender, it has been overwritten as `"_True"`.

Comment: Works perfectly! And thank you for the explanation. It's a clever trick.

Answer (score 1):

Put `legend=False` in `lineplot`, then add the legend yourself:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(
    x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3],
    style=True, dashes=[(2, 2)],
    label="Test", legend=False
)
ax.legend()
```